# optimizing page load with has_many and scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, include, has-many

I'm an experienced programmer who is relatively new to ruby/rails and databases. I have created a large website for signing up for courses. I thought I was being clever creating categories of course signups using scope and has_many. Logically, it encapsulates the information well, but my pages are now loading super-slow, and trying to eager load is confusing me.

I have models for Course, Person, CourseRole (student, teacher, etc.), and CourseSignup which includes one of each (Course, Person, CourseRole). It all works smoothly. Recently, I set up scopes in CourseRole to define the categories of signups (I had been hardcoding the role name, and wanted to get away from that). I then set up has_many relationships in Course for each of the categories. So, Course inherently `has_many course_signups`, and has my categories

```
has_many :student_signups, -> { CourseSignup.student }, class_name: 'CourseSignup', foreign_key: :course_id
has_many :teacher_signups, -> { CourseSignup.teacher }, class_name: 'CourseSignup', foreign_key: :course_id
```

etc. (I have 6 categories). I have a page that lists all courses and all of the signups for each course. Like:

```
Dodge Ball:
info about course
Students:
names of students
Teachers:
names of teachers
etc.
```

This page loads incredibly slowly. I was trying to add includes statements to the query (based on recommendations from the Bullet gem), but it actually makes it slower. This leads me to think I'm making this more complicated than I should, but I don't know enough to have a clue how to fix it. I imagine I should restructure my models. But I like the abstraction of the scopes/has_many

The page is generated by looping through rendering a partial which shows one course.

```
@courses = @cuco_session.assigned_courses.includes(:period).order('periods.start_time')
```

works but is very slow.

```
@courses = @cuco_session.assigned_courses
.includes(course_signups: [:person, :course_role])
.includes([:courses_rooms, :rooms])
.includes([:helper_signups, :student_signups, :volunteer_signups, :waiting_list_signups, :person_in_room_signups])
.includes(:period).order('periods.start_time')
```

Also works but is even slower.

Comment: What is `periods`? you didn't name that association on your description, do you have indexes on your tables? what's `@cuco_session`? what does `assigned_courses` do? maybe the log of bullet and the some code snippet of your view can help.

Comment: You need to provide more information to get better help - it is unclear why you would need so many tables in that second query example. Every time you do an includes you are joining a table and table joins are expensive. You want to limit the number of tables loaded for this page. I would not have a whole "CourseRole" object unless it really has more information than a single string column. You should look into Single Table Inheritance for CourseSignup where "teacher" and "student" are just different values in the "type" column. This looks like it should just be @course.course_signups

Answer (score 0):

We need more information about what is actually happening in the view to really answer why your page is slow.

Also a snippet of your log showing the actual SQL would be necessary.

You mention being new to using databases online with Rails. It's hard to give advice without more of a look into the structure of some of these models, but have you considered replacing CourseSignup with just a join table between Course and Person? It seems like that's what you're getting at here but it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

*has_many :student_signups, -> { CourseSignup.student }, class_name: 'CourseSignup', foreign_key: :course_id

has_many :teacher_signups, -> { CourseSignup.teacher }, class_name: 'CourseSignup', foreign_key: :course_id*

above code can be refactored using Single table inheritance

```
# app/models/person.rb
class Person < ApplicationRecord    
  #your code    
end

# app/models/teacher.rb
class Teacher < Person  
  #your code    
end

# app/models/student.rb
class Student < Person    
  #your code    
end
```

For Course Role you can have a separate master table of Role and put references of Person table and Role table in Course Role table

I hope above solution put some light on your question.